# Geometric distribution and Conditional probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I got this problem in my book.. I will directly go the last part which I could not solve.

$P(good condition) = 0.91854$ $P(bad condition)= 0.08146$

a random package check is checked by a company till there is a package in a bad condition .

1. what is the probability that the company will check exactly 4 packages?

2.it is known that the first 3 packages that were checked are in good condition , what is the probability that more than 8 packages will be checked(edit: the answer should be 0.654).

what I did was knowing that the last package (4th) has to be bad so it is $GGGB$ and the probability as stated for good is $P(good) = 0.91854$ and $P(bad)= 0.08146$ for bad we get $(0.91854)^3$ as in for 3 good (GGG) and one bad $0.08146$ so we multiply and get $(0.91854)^3$*$(0.08146)$= $0.063130$ which is right according to the book

from here I got that it is a geometric distribution so our function will be

$P(X=i)=(1-0.08146)^{i-1}$ *$0.08146$

$P(X=4)=(1-0.08146)^{4-1}$ *$0.08146$=$0.063130$

for the second part of the question

I didn't know how to use the Conditional probability I think that what is needed is $P(3<X≤8)$ but i got stuck.. cannot think of a way to use Geometric distribution or Conditional probability.

thanks for any tips and help much appreciated and sorry for the English mistakes it is hard to translate it , hope it is somehow understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that [Geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) is a memoryless distribution thus the fact that you know that the first 3 packages are good changes your request in calculating

$$P(X>5)=1-P(X\leq 5)=0.91854^5\approx0.6539$$

To calculate it you can use the fact that the CDF of your rv is known...

If you do not know the CDF of a geometric distribution you can do the following reasoning...the probability to have more than 5 failures is exactly the probability of having 5 consecutive failures...after this events any event can happen....thus you probability is

$$0.91854\times0.91854\times0.91854\times0.91854\times0.91854\times 1\approx0.654$$